# React. Add/Remove event listener

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, use-effect, event-listener, removeeventlistener

There are 6 posts with information about users. If the name and email in the post are too big, they are cut off. When hovering over the cropped element - a block with full information appears next to it. If registration is successful - user list is updated - newest one in the beginning. I put events onMouseOver and onMouseOut on items. Is it necessary to removeEventListener? Tried to do it in return UseEffect, but selected items = null
[There are current elements[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7PpD.jpg)

Comment: The question is not clear. If you are asking about removing listeners added using react - the answer is no, you don't need to remove them manually.  Otherwise it is not clear why you would even need to use native DOM methods.  Please read [ask] and how to create [mcve].

Answer (score 6):

Read the article about **events** - https://en.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

You can add **events** using `useEffect`. `return` triggered when component *unmount*. Code example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleClick() {
    console.log("click")
  }

  window.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
}, []);
```

Comment: Это понятно. Вопрос в другом. Например, если навешиваем события на window, после в UseEffect должны отписаться в return (при unmount), но если вешать события на сам элемент, например "mouseOver" на тег <p>, нужно ли отписаться от него в UseEffect так как это делали с window

Comment: Ответ - да. Прошу прощения за столь поздний ответ